# How to accept the PUT request data in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, multipartform-data, laravel-6, form-data

I did not encounter problem with fetching, storing, and deleting data using `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`. It's just updating that I've been stucked for almost an hour.

My question is why Laravel does not get any data? And how should I fix this?

---

Here is the data I passed from front-end

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("name", this.teamData.name);
formData.append("image", this.teamData.image);
formData.append("year_joined", this.teamData.year_joined);
formData.append("_method", "PUT");
//more code here..
```

I am sure that the data was passed

[image]

Method I use from server

```
public function update(Request $request, Team $team)
{
    return response()->json(request()->all());
}
```

The problem is, it returns none even I passed existing FormData.

Comment: Please share your `update` route

Comment: @ChristopheHubert `Route::resource('teams', 'TeamController')->except(['create','show','edit']);`

I there is no problem with route/sending request as you can see in the screenshot the data-request was successfully sent.

Comment: I found the answer. I sent `PUT` in my axios instead of `POST`. this link was helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691938/patch-and-put-request-does-not-working-with-form-data