# Laravel file upload over API HTTP PUT works locally but does not on AWS

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I have a simple Laravel app with endpoints for file upload.

When I call `POST` endpoint to create (and upload) brand new file, everything works on both local (docker) and AWS.

I do `HTTP POST` to `api/file` with payload:

[image]

I pick file from my desktop, provide name, type and model's UUID (polymorphic relationship).

However… when I want to overwrite this file I have a `HTTP PUT` endpoint: `api/file/<UUID OF PREVIOUSLY UPLOADED FILE>` with payload:

[image]

The issue is bizarre because I don't get any PHP issues. Laravel simply cannot pass the validation because it somehow completely DOES NOT SEE the payload on AWS. On local (docker) this works with no issues whatsoever.

I'm pretty sure this is AWS related but I'm running out of clues what is the culprit. Below is the validation message bag but I swear I pass `type` and `model_uuid` (screenshot number 2).

```
{
    "error": [
        "Model type is required.",
        "Model UUID is required."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe that one can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691938/patch-and-put-request-does-not-working-with-form-data

Comment: Did you try the same file for your POST endpoint on aws as well? Is there any waf setup in aws to block the PUT method or file size limit?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, with html form standards, you can only use `GET` or `POST` for form submission. Here you are sending your form-data which is considered as a form with `PUT` and it is not acceptable.

So you have two options, either switch to `POST` or do a **method spoofing** that Laravel supports.

For method spoofing, make your request verb `POST` and in your form-data add an `_method` input with value `PUT`. Basically you are sending a POST request but Laravel request handler will assume it as `PUT` internally. And you can define your route as `Route::put(....)`.

The method override in Laravel Kernel, occurs [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/345c08623a9ba2435a696e34b6c37197d7e3ca3b/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php#L108).