# laravel checkbox doesn't update to database laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update the user status in my laravel project with a checkbox. If I change the value in the database it show's up on my checkbox. But if I change it with in my website with a form the status remains the same. I think something might be wrong with my controller. Can someone help?

In my view:

```
<form action="{{ route('users.change_status', $user) }}" class="form" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @method('PATCH')
    <label>body</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="status" value="{{$user->status}}" @if($user->status) checked @endif>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="button is-link is-outlined" value="{{$user->status}}" >>Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my controller:

```
    public function change_status(Request $request, User $user)
        {
            //dd($user);

            // Validate posted form data
            $validated = $request->validate([
                'status' => 'required',
            ]);

            if (!$validated) { return redirect()->back();}
            $user->update($request->all());

            return redirect()->back();

        }
```

And my routes in web.php:

```
Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users.index');
Route::patch('/change_status/{user}', [UserController::class, 'change_status'])->name('users.change_status');
```

Comment: if you want to have the value of checkbox in `status` POST filed, then you have to give it `name="status"` instead of `name="body"`.

Comment: @AdrianKokot I changed it but the problem is still the same

Comment: Also, you shouldn't setting the `value` property of checkbox. `value` should contain what you want the value to be when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: how does your model look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PATCH and PUT Request Does not Working with form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691938/patch-and-put-request-does-not-working-with-form-data)

Answer (score 0):

You should add status property to fillable array on User model

```
protected $fillable = ['status',...other properties];
```

Comment: I already did that

Answer (score 0):

First in your code you have some spams(in controller) and some syntax error (in html).

## html

Extra `>` in button, change to this:

```
<button type="submit" class="button is-link is-outlined" value="{{$user->status}}" >Update</button>
```

## controller

You dont need to assessment the validation to an new varaible, because the validation if has errorm automaticly return back the request, so you don't need the if statement and also the update method accepts array as input, change your code to this:

```php
$request->validate([
                'status' => 'required',
            ]);
    $user->update([$request->all()]);
```

if your status column(in databas) is boolean, you most change the status request, because the checkbox value on checked is `on` and on uncheck is  `null` so you most use this code:

```php
$request->validate([
                'status' => 'required',
            ]);
    if(isset($request->status)){
        $status = true;
    }else{
        $status = false;
    }
    $user->update([
        'status' => $status,
    ]);
```

It's will be work, else, check your **model fillable** and add the status field  to that:

```php
protected $fillable = ['status',...];
```