# Laravel Auth FormRequest works when accepting JSON, fails when accepting form data

Tags: laravel, insomnia, laravel-formrequest

This is very strange. I have an endpoint that accepts a PUT request.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Dingo\Api\Http\FormRequest;
class UpdateTestRequest extends FormRequest
{
    
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true // guaranteed to work
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'is_invited' => 'required|boolean',
          'is_span_invited' => 'required|boolean',
        ];
    }
}
```

When I make the request in insomnia, it works fine when accepting a JSON payload.[image]

However, changing to type Multipart form data and PUT'ing again - the UpdateTestRequest is run again but it fails. Laravel doesn't seem to see the values in `is_invited` nor `is_span_invited`. Doesn't matter is the expected value is a string, int etc.

Very strange.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691938/patch-and-put-request-does-not-working-with-form-data

Answer (score 0):

I think true is being parsed as string by laravel backend. Did you try sending 0 and 1 instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use _method="PUT" in request body and POST. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#form-method-spoofing