# Passing data using HTTP PUT method works only when using query params and not from body

Tags: php, laravel, postman

Basically what my controller does is update the data from database. However when testing the api for the controller, the data passed through query parameters works while data passed from body doesn't.

For eg: When passing data from query parameters
[image: When passing data from query parameters]

vs When passing data from body
[image: When passing data from body]

My controller looks like this

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if (Contact::where('id', $id)->exists()) {
            $editedContactData = Contact::find($id);
            $editedContactData->province =  is_null($request->province) ? $editedContactData->province : $request->province;
            $editedContactData->district = is_null($request->district) ? $editedContactData->district : $request->district;
            $editedContactData->local = is_null($request->local) ? $editedContactData->local : $request->local;
            $editedContactData->spokesman =  is_null($request->spokesman) ? $editedContactData->spokesman : $request->spokesman;
            $editedContactData->phone = is_null($request->phone) ? $editedContactData->phone : $request->phone;
            $editedContactData->email = is_null($request->email) ? $editedContactData->email : $request->email;

            $editedContactData->save();
            
            return response()->json([
                "message" => "Contact Updated successfully",
                "editedContactData" => $editedContactData
            ], 201);
        }else{
            return response()->json([
                "message" => "Contact Not Found."
            ], 404);
        }
    }
```

I think there is problem with my controller, yet I'm unable to find the solutions. Any problem the code might have?

For anybody who want to see headers passed
[image: headers]

Comment: What headers are you using in both requests(please add it to question)?

Comment: You should use `Body` => `raw` and change the last dropdown (besides GraphQL) to `JSON`

Comment: @IbrahimHammed but the controller will be accepting form data from front-end, thus JSON would be hard to do.

Comment: Have you seen this before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60781688/9077347

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50692302/9077347

Answer (score 0):

You can use `post()` to get body parameters

```
$datarequest = $this->input->post(); // this will contain all body parameters
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

try to send put request like this, it may works.

Comment: update request donot allow post as a request, they need put request